# Function error handling in Swift

Tags: swift, error-handling

I am implementing Local Search in my CoreLocation and MapKit frimeworks based app. I am following this [Tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_MapKit_Local_Search_in_iOS_8_and_Swift)

I am getting error below error :

> Cannot convert value of type '(MKLocalSearchResponse!, NSError!) ->
>   ()' to expected argument type 'MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler' (aka
>   '(Optional, Optional) -> ()')

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate{
    private let LocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    private var previousPoint:CLLocation?
    private var totalMovementDistance:CLLocationDistance = 0




    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!


    @IBOutlet var searchText: UITextField!
    var matchingItems: [MKMapItem] = [MKMapItem]()

    @IBAction func textFieldReturn(sender:AnyObject) {
        sender.resignFirstResponder()
        mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
        self.performSearch()

    }

    @IBOutlet var latitudeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var longitudeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var horizontalAccuracy: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var altitudeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var verticalAccuracyLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var distanceTraveledLabel: UILabel!






    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        LocationManager.delegate = self
        LocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        LocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }



    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print("Authorization Status Changed to \(status.rawValue)")
        switch status {
        case .Authorized, .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
            LocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true

        default:
            LocationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            mapView.showsUserLocation = false
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        let errorType = error.code == CLError.Denied.rawValue ? "Access Denied": "Error \(error.code)"
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Location Manager Error", message: errorType, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: {action in})
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func performSearch() {

        matchingItems.removeAll()
        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchText.text
        request.region = mapView.region

        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

        search.startWithCompletionHandler { (localResponse:MKLocalSearchResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in


            if error != nil {
                print("Error occured in search: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            } else if localResponse == 0 {
                print("No matches found")
            } else {
                print("Matches found")

                for item in localResponse.mapItems  {
                    print("Name = \(item.name)")
                    print("Phone = \(item.phoneNumber)")

                    self.matchingItems.append(item as MKMapItem)
                    print("Matching items = \(self.matchingItems.count)")

                    var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                    annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
                    annotation.title = item.name
                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                }
            }
        }
    }


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let newLocation = (locations as [CLLocation]) [locations.count - 1]

        let latitudeString = String(format: "%g\u{00B0}", newLocation.coordinate.latitude)
        latitudeLabel.text = latitudeString

        let longitudeString = String(format: "%g\u{00B0}", newLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        longitudeLabel.text = longitudeString

        let horizontalAccuracyString = String(format: "%gm", newLocation.horizontalAccuracy)
        horizontalAccuracy.text = horizontalAccuracyString

        let altitudeString = String(format: "%gm", newLocation.altitude)
        altitudeLabel.text = altitudeString

        let verticalAccuracyString = String(format: "%gm", newLocation.verticalAccuracy)
        verticalAccuracyLabel.text = verticalAccuracyString

        if newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0 {
            //invalid accuracy
            return

        }


        if newLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 100 ||
            newLocation.verticalAccuracy > 50 {
                return
        }

        if previousPoint == nil {
            totalMovementDistance = 0
            let start = Place(title:"Strating Point", subtitle:"This is where we started", coordinate:newLocation.coordinate)
            mapView.addAnnotation(start)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newLocation.coordinate, 100, 100)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated:true)


        }else {
            print("movement distance: \(newLocation.distanceFromLocation(previousPoint!))")
            totalMovementDistance += newLocation.distanceFromLocation(previousPoint!)

        }

        previousPoint = newLocation

        let distanceString = String(format: "%gm", totalMovementDistance)
        distanceTraveledLabel.text = distanceString



    }



}
```

Error is on this line:

```
search.startWithCompletionHandler({(response:
            MKLocalSearchResponse!,
```

Edited:

[image]

Comment: The error that you're receiving is because this variables are of type optional, for access then you need to use ?.. something like: `error?.localizedDescription` or first unwrap the values `if let error = error{ // your code}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the ! in the arguments with ? (because that's the signature of the method)
Example:

```
    search.startWithCompletionHandler { (localResponse:MKLocalSearchResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer and comment It helped to remove error.

Answer (score 1):

The error message simply says that the signature of the method is wrong, because it expects optional types.

Confirm it by pressing <kbd>⇧⌘0</kbd> and typing `MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler` and you will see

> typealias MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler = (MKLocalSearchResponse?,
>   NSError?) -> Void

So, it's

```
search.startWithCompletionHandler({(response:
        MKLocalSearchResponse?,
        error: NSError?) in ...
```

but you can – and should – omit the type annotations

```
search.startWithCompletionHandler({(response, error) in ...
```

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my code as you suggested Now I get 3 more error I am not getting how to overcome with that. sorry I am complete beginner in this.

Comment: `localResponse` is not the same as `response`. Check the consistency of your parameter names

Comment: Yes, you used the code from the answer of José, but he wrote `localResponse` rather than your original parameter name `response` which breaks your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
func performSearch() {

    var matchingItems = [MKMapItem]()
    let mapView = MKMapView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,300,300))

    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Restaurants 30518"
    request.region = mapView.region

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

    search.startWithCompletionHandler { (response, error) in

        if let error = error  {
            print("Error occured in search: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else if let response = response {
            print("Got response")
            if response.mapItems.count == 0 {
                print("No matches found")
            } else {
                print("Matches found")

                for item in response.mapItems as [MKMapItem] {
                    print("Name = \(item.name)")
                    print("Phone = \(item.phoneNumber)")

                    matchingItems.append(item as MKMapItem)
                    print("Matching items = \(matchingItems.count)")

                    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                    annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
                    annotation.title = item.name
                    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The response and error are optionals, don't force unwrap them.

Comment: The forced unwrapping is no problem in this case. If an error occurs, `error` is definitely not `nil`, and if there is no error, `response` is definitely not `nil`.

Comment: @vadian I meant in the method signature.  (response: MKLocalSearchResponse!, error: NSError!) is wrong,  He should leave them as optionals in the method signature and unwrap them inside (could be forced I guess but not at the level where it was done in the question).